# How can I bind a dynamic data model to a custom listview cell?

Tags: listview, data-binding, xamarin.forms

Hopefully I'm using the correct terms in that question.

I am trying to replicate a very flexible data presentation model that we use in our desktop applications. We have a proprietary data server, and a scripting language to access it. The server returns a header with the data that defines how many fields comprise a row, and the names and types for each field. Our desktop application can then configure the table/grid/spreadsheet/(whatever you want to call a dataset represented in rows and columns) it presents to the user on the fly. This allows us to customize the data each customer sees without having to create custom applications.

Any hints on how I might accomplish this? I was thinking of using a listview, and building the cell at runtime, but I can't figure out how to get the data into the created cells. All the examples I've found that have created the cell layout at runtime are still based on a data model with static properties that can be bound. I essentially need to bind to an array index or element.

I want to do something like this (and I'm sure it's riddled with errors):

```
class AResult
{
    public short[] FieldSizes;
    public short[] FieldTypes;
    public string[] FieldNames;
    public string[][] FieldValues;

    public short FieldCount;
    public short RowCount;

    AResult(string query)
    {
            ... do stuff...
    }
}

public void OnQueryButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    AResult result = new AResult("some query");
    var newtemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        var newview = new ViewCell {
            View = new StackLayout {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
            }
        }
        return newview;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<result.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        var lbl = new Label();
        lbl.BindingContext = i; // <-- Yes I know this doesn't work...
        newtemplate.View.Children.Add(lbl);  // Or this either...
    }
}
```

But that totally doesn't work.

If you know of any example code that does something even remotely like this, I'd really appreciate a pointer to it. Or any other hints or recommendations.

Thanks!
-Karen

Comment: Hi, a have successfully used the same approach but with xamarin devexpress grid. we also have an app that reads a metadata schema from db and builds dynamic. Would you like to show you the solution with grid?

Comment: Yes, please. I was considering using the DevExpress grid, we use them extensively in our core application, but am not yet convinced it's the best solution for what we're trying to do. It sounds like you're doing exactly what I'm trying to do, so I'd love to see your solution!

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is coming from Hell so don't freak out.

The dynamic grid is populated by two web api services, with 1st one carrying the column descriptions in order to add the Columns to the grid and the 2nd one with the actual data.

The 1st returns a list of Columninfo

```
public class ColumnDescDto 
{
    public string PropetyName { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public bool IsNullable { get; set; }
    public string DataTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

and the 2nd assume that returns the following objects

```
public class Car
{  
    public string collor{ get; set; }
    public int year{ get; set; }
    public double price{ get; set; }
}
```

So in the ViewModel i cal the services

```
var spdata = await _dataClient.GetSpData(pagectrl.SpParameterInputServiceModel); //List<JObject>
var spschema = await _dataClient.GetSpSchema(pagectrl.SpParameterInputServiceModel);//List<ColumnDescDto>
```

The `spdata` has a type of `List<JObject>` not `List<Car>`. Why JObject? because the data is dynamic. I cannot deserialize them in a specific type because i do not know it.

Then create a dummy list which we will bind to grid. Why? Because we want the grid to create the rows then we will use an event to add the values. So

```
var listcnt = new List<SimpleCounter>();
for (var i = 0; i < spdata.Count; i++)
{
    var cnt = new SimpleCounter { NoName = i.ToString() };
    listcnt.Add(cnt);
}
DataCounter = new ObservableCollection<SimpleCounter>(listcnt);
```

In you Page or View do the following

```
public GenericGridView()
{

    var grid = new GridControl
            {
                TotalSummaryVisibility = VisibilityState.Always,
                SortMode = GridSortMode.Single,
                AllowEditRows = false,
                AllowDeleteRows = false,
                AutoGenerateColumnsMode = AutoGenerateColumnsMode.None
            };
    grid.CustomUnboundColumnData += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var colschema = spschema.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropetyName == args.Column.FieldName);
                if (args.Column.FieldName == colschema.PropetyName && args.IsGetData)
                {
                    var model = (SimpleCounter) args.RowData.DataObject;
                    var val = spdata[Convert.ToInt32(model.NoName)][args.Column.FieldName];                    
                    args.Value = MobileHelper.ConvertJObjectValue(colschema.DataType, (string) val);
                }
            };

    foreach (var col in spschema)
    {               

        if (MobileHelper.TypeIsNumeric(col.DataType))
        {
            var gcol = new NumberColumn()
            {
                UnboundType = MobileHelper.ConvertToUnboundColumnType(col.DataType),
                FieldName = col.PropetyName,
                Caption = col.PropetyName,
                DisplayFormat = MobileHelper.GetFormatNumber(),

            };

            grid.Columns.Add(gcol);
        }
        else if (MobileHelper.TypeIsString(col.DataType))
           {
                grid.Columns.Add(new TextColumn()
               {
                    UnboundType = MobileHelper.ConvertToUnboundColumnType(col.DataType),
                    FieldName = col.PropetyName,
                    Caption = col.PropetyName,

                });
            }
        }

        grid.SetValue(GridControl.ItemsSourceProperty, DataCounter);
}
```

All your data are loading on `grid.CustomUnboundColumnData` event